# Draw using WPF with c#

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

i need to draw something like the image below using WPF... 
i need this in xaml code and in c# in code behind.

[image: image example]

**I'm just asking for some tips on how to achieve this picture. I've been trying without any success, so I was asking for some hint or help, I do not pretend that I solved the problem myself.**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't really think this is a bad question, it's just asked poorly.  It would help a lot if the question indicated what the intended use was.  For instance, it's one thing to just be able to draw this on the screen; it's another (and much more interesting and useful problem) to create a custom control that displays a color wheel whose regions are selectable.

Comment: I don't imagine this is much more difficult than drawing a pie chart. In fact, I would research that, and probably stumble across the solution. It's called a "Doughnut" chart in Excel, by the way.

Comment: A question was indeed asked, but it was put in the form of a statement (e.g.  "I'm just asking...").  For those who can't see the question, think about it this way:  "How can I create this visual pictured using WPF?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to draw in XAML use a path. This draws a little Rotate right image with XAML. The nice thing is its all vector based.

```
F 0 = Even Fill
M 10,0 = Move to 10 across and down 0
V 15 = Draw vertical line for 15
H 18 = Draw horizontal line for 18
Z = Close this object
```

You can draw other types of objects with the drawing commands. <strike>[Look at them here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx#drawcommands)</strike>

```
        <Style x:Key="RotatePlus90Path" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Pen.LineJoin" Value="Miter"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="F 0 M 10,0 V 15 H 18 Z M 1,12 S 0,5 8,5 M 8,5 L 6,7 6,3 8,5 "></Setter>
    </Style>

            <Button Height="22" ToolTip="Rotate +90 degrees" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Rotate90Plus}" Background="{x:Null}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource RotatePlus90Path}"></Path>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
```